# Изменение формата времени Calendar

Tags: java, android

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int h = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int m = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
System.out.println(h + ":" + m);
```

данный код выводит время в 24 часов формате, как сделать чтоб выводил в 12 часовом именно используя Calendar.

Comment: Метки (теги) нужны для того, чтобы выделить основные моменты ВОПРОСА, по которым другие пользователи быстрее смогут найти решение аналогичной проблемы, а не для демонстрации собственных предпочтений в выборе IDE. Вопрос никак не связан с проблемами при работе IDE Android Studio и этот тег в вопросе не нужен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выводить форматированное время удобнее через [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). В Вашем случае будет как то так:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
System.out.println(format.format(new Date()));
```

Comment: Спасибо, этот вариант я знал, а нельзя используя класс календарь это сделать?

Comment: Простите но я не могу понять чего же вы хотите. Хотите легко и просто форматировать дату в строку - используйте SimpleDateFormat. Хотите работать с числовыми значениями - используйте Calendar. С классом Calendar вы конечно можете тоже самое, только всё форматирование вы берете на себя и судя по вопросу не справляетесь.

Comment: да не совсем понял как форматировать это в Calendar, спасибо за помощь сделаю как вы сказали через SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 2):

Взято отсюда
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

> For the time of day:
>    HOUR_OF_DAY
>    AM_PM + HOUR

```
int h = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int am_pm = cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM); // 0 - АМ, 1 - РМ
```

Comment: не совсем понятно, я читал там, какой код должен быть тогда

Comment: добавил пример кода

Comment: возвращает не правильно время, я так пробовал

Comment: и в чем же интересно неправильность возвращаемого времени?

Comment: ну к примеру он не выводит время в формате 01:56 PM, а выводит только который час (без минут) и 0 или 1 т.к. cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM) возвращает как вы сами писали 0 и 1, а нужно чтоб возвращал нормальное время типа 01:56 PM

Comment: @java Calendar вообще ни в каком формате ничего не выводит. Вы с его помощью получаете составные части даты/времени в числовом виде какие вам нужны, а дальше только от вас зависит как их форматировать. Хотите преобразовать `cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM)` в AM или PM - делайте это сами: `cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0 ? "AM" : "PM"`

Comment: ок, спасибо что объяснили)